# Deploying R Shiny App on Bluemix using dashDB

Tags: r, shiny, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I'm hoping someone can help with deploying an R Shiny application built on dashDB on Bluemix.

I have built a Shiny application that currently runs on my local machine. However, I now want to host this app on Bluemix using the dashDB service to store the relevant data. I have the app running in rStudio on dashDB, and it runs as expected when I click "Run App".

My question is how do I go from this stage to deploying the shiny app to a web application, accessible to end users through a web link?

I have looked at some other questions about deploying Shiny apps to Bluemix (e.g. [Unable to push Sample Shiny App to Bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357382/unable-to-push-sample-shiny-app-to-bluemix), http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-rtwitter-app/index.html) but these seem to be concerned with deploying from a local app straight to Bluemix. I can't find any guidance on deploying from the dashDB service.

Is this possible? Has anyone else been able to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Just to make sure that I understand: You have data in dashDB. You have R Shiny working from rStudio. However, the final step, of publishing the Shiny app to some URL that you can share to people, that is the part that fails?

Comment: If all of that is correct, may I ask a quick question. Are you currently publishing any web application at all on Bluemix? Or is it just stuff in the console so-far? (I am trying to duplicate your setup.) Thanks very much!

Comment: That is correct - currently I don't have any web application live, just what I have developed in the console. I'm trying to figure out how to publish it to some URL such that it maintains the connection to dashDB and can be accessed via that link

Answer (score 0):

dashDB has a REST API that can be used to launch R scripts/applications. So you should be able to use that to launch the R scripts (ui.R, server.R) this way, which stands up the R web application.

See here: https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/wp-content/themes/projectnext-clouddata/dashDB/
The REST endpoint to use is POST with /rscript/{filename}

Comment: Thanks Torsten, I will investigate this!